# Is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just ran across this recent question: [Data Structure and Algorithm for a 3D Volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24293821)

My gut reaction is that it's off-topic because it's rather broad and seems to be asking for recommendations and/or opinions.  However, it's from a 57K user so I'm wondering if my understanding of off-topic is somehow faulty.

Comment: I see see why you think that it's opinion based, but I don't really feel that it is.  It uses some of the keywords that often signal opinion based questions, but at it's core he has a specified programming problem and he needs it solved.  That's not opinion based.  To broad on the other hand, seems applicable, although not being an expert in that sub-domain, I couldn't say if there's a short simple answer to the question, which would make it not broad.

Comment: Seems likely "too broad" to me.

Comment: It seems somewhat on the broad side of what is typically encouraged on SO. I don't think there's going to be one "correct" answer. And there could be opinions about the "best" approach. In that sense, it looks borderline to me. I wouldn't call it **primarily** opinion based, though. It's a well defined problem that allows technical answers. I wouldn't give it a close vote myself. Mainly because it's a well written and interesting question, which probably puts it above 95% of the content waiting for attention in the CV queue.

Comment: There's an SO user that's banking his rep.  That's the way it *should* work.  Give a lot, feel free to expect something back.  2000+ answers is a pretty good piggy bank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question seems fine to me.  It is sufficiently specified, clearly-asked, is about programming, and is reasonably confined in scope.  In short, it's a programming question that is answerable.

For questions to close, look for things like

- product recommendations,
- questions that are under-specified (not enough information to be answerable),
- questions that ask for too much,
- questions that are unclear,
- questions that were already asked and answered.
- requests for polls, searches, big lists, extended tutorials and the like.

The questions that need closing are the unanswerable ones and the ones with undesirable forum-like behaviors.